# List all Nodes a user ever edited

Tags: 7, views, workbench

I want to do display a list with Views, which shows all Nodes the current user have ever edited.

The workbench Module includes a list like I need, 'workbench_edited', this view uses the Filter

```
(revision user) User: Current (Yes)
```

[image]

But the problem is that this View only checks if the user is the editor of the CURRENT REVISION, it does not check all revions of a node, just the current one.

Is there a way to list all Nodes a User ever edited? So that Views checks all revisions of a node?

Answer (score 1):

The "content revision : content" relationship in that view needs to be based on the nid rather than the vid. Remove that existing relationship and add back the one that has the same name but uses the nid.

Then you'll need to fix the relationships that have been broken since a number of the fields, filters, and sort options relied on that relationship.  You can just step through each of the fields and filters, open their settings, then click "apply" to re-save them to fix the relationships.

In the settings for the title field you need to switch it to link to the revision rather than the node, in order to avoid an error.

And I also noticed that, for some reason, the exposed "published" filter got switched to having a default value of "no" after doing these steps.  I have no idea why that happened, but switch it back to "any".

Here's an export of the View you should end up with: http://pastebin.com/a9tXXCqP

Comment: yes there are two: The revision NID of the content revision. and The Version-ID, wich belongs to the version of the content. But if I choose the first one and remove the second I get too few nodes.

Comment: You need to remove the revision ID relationship then add the NID option...the one labeled "The revision NID of the content revision.".  After doing that you'll need to step through each and every field, filter, and sort option.  Click the link to open the settings, then without changing anything, click "apply" at the bottom.  This is because there are a bunch of broken relationships that need to be fixed.  Once you've done that it should work.

Comment: This does not work, if I change the relationship i get no results.

Comment: When I tested it randomly set the published filter's default value to "no", so make sure that's not tripping you up.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a list of pages the user has edited (has made a revision on) by using the following setup:

[image]